# can we use AddOrUpdate in Entity Framework to update only specific value in table if it exists for a key else Add new row/entry into the table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have a table

```
-------------
ID - CTypeID - ServiceID - CKey - CValue - 

CEntity consists of -----
ID (Guid) - CTypeID (Guid) - ServiceID (Guid) - CKey (string) - CValue (string)
```

currently i am using

```
public int SaveConfig(Guid serviceId, Guid TypeId, NameValueCollection cCollection)
{
    int result = 0;

    var configurationEntities = cCollection.AllKeys.SelectMany( cCollection.GetValues, (ck, cv) => new CEntity()
    {
        CTypeId = TypeId,
        CKey = ck,
        CValue = cv,
        ServiceId = serviceId
    }).ToList();

    using (var context = new CDataContext(_connectionString))
    {
        foreach (var cEntity in cEntities)
        {
            context.CEntities.AddOrUpdate(entry => new { entry.ServiceId, entry.CTypeId, entry.CKey }, cEntity);
        }

        result = context.SaveChanges(); 
    }

    return result;
}
```

the above code is making a new entry of cEntity into the table
with ID as empty guid.

in the above code I want to fetch for existing entry against  ServiceId , TypeID & CKey if entry Exists it should update the CValue for CKey from cEntity where I am passing the ServiceId, TypeID & CKey.
And if no entry is found it should add new row with values in CEntity into table where ID should be newly generated.
 Any Suggestions ??

Comment: I would advise against using `.AddOrUpdate` in production code, as it is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var context = new CDataContext(_connectionString))
{
    foreach (var cEntity in cEntities)
    {
        var entity = context.CEntities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceId == cEntity.ServiceId && x.TypeID == cEntity.TypeID && x.CKey == cEntity.CKey);

        if(entity == null)
            context.CEntities.Add(cEntity);
        else 
        {
            entity.CValue = cEntity.CValue;
            entity.CKey = cEntity.CKey;
        }
    }

    result = context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```